# Is there a way to trigger Sitecore's bot detection on purpose?

Tags: xdb

I am working on a feature that should behave differently based on whether or not Sitecore believes that the current Contact is legitimate or a malicious bot.

I am using `ContactClassification.IsRobot(Tracker.Current.Contact.System.Classification)` to determine whether the current contact has been flagged as a robot. It's been pretty easy for me to persist this Boolean value on a view model, surface it in my view, and change the behavior on the front end as a result.

The main issue I am facing is testing my feature. I would be easy for me to inject a superficial True/False value for testing purposes, however, I'm more interested in testing the feature as a true bot would see it. This begs the question: Is there a known way to have a visit flagged as a robot for testing purposes?

My goal is not to have to develop an actual malicious bot just to test my feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots are not necessarily malicious. I believe every Sitecore site in the world welcomes GoogleBot when it swings by for a visit.

For what you want to do, I suggest adding a new agent string to the `Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config` file and call up your site using same agent string.

Alternatively, in the same file, set `127.0.0.1` under `<excludedIPAddresses>` to mark local sessions as robot per default. This, you would need to switch on and off however.

The file, on Sitecore 9, is located in `\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking`

Comment: Thanks Mark, I like the user agent approach as its easy to spoof with something like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/iojaoainolpgkpojokmeclhidjolocci?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach whereby I forego adding the `VisitorIdentification()` method call in my main layout when I want to pretend I am a robot. Sitecore automatically flags all traffic with a visitor identification level of 925 (IsAutoDetectedRobot) until they can prove they are human. By excluding this method call, that never happens:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["sc_robot"]))
{
    @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
}
```